# Is there a work around for an object oriented front-end in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm having some problems with an event handler in the object below. I can't remember the error message but it basically said that it could not find the function. The code below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
var anObject = function () {
  var n = 0;  

  var HandleClick(e) {
    n ++;
  };

  return {
    Init: function () {
      var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
      var handler = app.createServerHandler("HandleClick");
      var com = UiApp.LoadComponent("MyGui", {prefix: "a"});

      com.getElementById("button").addClickHandler(handler);
    }
  }
}
```

Would really appreciate a work-around if possible, if that is not possible then please tell me what you would suggest because I'm not sure how best to get around this.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All handler functions must be top level functions on your script. It's not possible to have it inside an object like this.

Comment: I don't suppose you know of any documentation confirming this do you?

Comment: @ckuhn203 No, there isn't any, AFAIK.